# Unique TimeUUID in cluster environment vs. Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, unique, cluster-computing, uuid

I'd like to generate unique TimeUUID values which in next step will be stored in Cassandra as a key. As I checked out a creation of TimeUUID in com.eaio package is thread safe and it's fine but my application will be deployed into cluster. So what then ? I need some functionality of synchronized creation of TimeUUID. I see only one solution: create a simple application which will serve generator method over JMS / RMI

Any comments / ideas ?

Regards

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs are designed to be generated across multiple machines without conflict or need for coordination. A TimeUUID (also known as a v1 UUID) should be a combination of the machine's MAC address and a time component. The included MAC address ensures that the value will be unique across machines.